Kalsarp Yog, Mangal Dosh, Shani Dosh
I have a question please. So I have so much bad luck mostly obstacles, betrayals, disappointments and lots of struggle. I have Kalsarp Yog, Mangal Dosh, Shani Dosh. I have done several pujas, Gemstone / Metal remedies, havans, prayers, but it seems like nothing is working. What could be reason that such a strong negative impacts in my life are not going away? What can a person do just adjust with it? Is there any permanent remedy to solve kalsarp yog and other doshas in one's kundali?

Yes, living life as per Dharma will either eliminate suffering altogether. In essence, Dharma is following the 4 principles of No Illicit Sex, No Intoxication, No Gambling, No Meat eating in accordance to Shrimad Bhagavatam Any spiritual practice will then be able to give its full results. https://harekrishnatemple.com/4regs.html

I am vegetarian do my prayers on time and no bad stuff, so what could be reasons and how to resolve these doshas?

Keep an eye on your Brahmacharya as well. Avoid foods with onion and garlic. Problems will be there until that dasha ends. Need to be patient. But you can reduce the suffering felt. If you can do these during a difficult dasha when the mind will not allow you, the subsequent ones will pass peacefully. It's a good time for spiritual progress. You can also worship Lord Shiva daily (e.g., through a Stotra and offering everything you eat to him first) as only He can change one's destiny.

I dont eat onion and garlic at all. I have done Shiva ji's mantra and stotra and always offer Hanumanji and Shiva ji first - it seems like I always get cheated, betrayed, disappointed and it seems like if I do something good it comes back negative 10 times. it's been over 30 years, is there any limit to suffering or no

There's no option to remain patient and have faith. You'll have to chant a Mantra which needs no Diksha (e.g., Samba Sadashiva) everyday for a few hours (e.g., morning) and then constantly to the best of your capacity with a prayerful mood. There're no shortcuts for some karmas if we've caused pain to others. If we have faith, all karmas can be reversed, and we'll be purified very soon by His grace.

I don't remember causing pain to anyone, unless accidently but i do not remember. 30 years seems too much to me and I do meditation a lot with mantra recitation, seems suffering increasing instead of decreasing I am still having intact faith but for some reason it's not working. can black magic be the cause or some powerful evil entity at play?

Karmas are an accumulation of many lifetimes and not just one which is why some enjoy since birth and some suffer. It could be but in very very rare cases. If you approach some fake tantrik, he'd loot you or cast some spell and cause more trouble. Please surrender to God and tell him I'm fully yours. I don't have any other solution.

Thank you for your advice.

Glad to help. https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/18/66/

1) Kāla Sarpa Yoga: This yoga is formed when all seven planets including Lagna(Ascendant) are at the clutches of Rahu-Ketu. This can be easily understood with help of a sample horoscope.
Sample Horoscope: Born: 20/Nov/1981, 8:52 AM, Coordinates: 70 E 58 and 11 N 0.
Observe in the above sample horoscope that Rahu-Ketu axis falls across Cancer-Capricorn signs and the 7 planets with Lagna(falls in Sagittarius) have occupied signs from Leo to Sagittarius clockwise. This formation is known as Kāla Sarpa Yoga.
Very recently, I happened to see a lady horoscope with full and complete Kāla Sarpa Yoga and running Rahu major dasha at the same time. She has been earning around 2 lakhs rupees per month and being well off. But she is 30 being unmarried and her parents are worried. The marriage delay is totally attributed to other afflictions, however I am keenly observing this horoscope for Kāla Sarpa Yoga has any role to play because the running major dasha is Rahu who is placed in viraya sthāna(12th house)!
Beware-1: Please be informed that this yoga lacks scriptural support.
Beware-2: Since all the 7 planets including Lagna(Ascendant) are caught in  between Rahu-Ketu axis, these two planets (Rahu and Ketu) have a say in all matters overriding even in major dasha and Bhukti of other planets until native's demise. Particularly, during Major Dasha or Bukti of either Rahu or Ketu the effect will be severe.
Beware-3: Even though it lacks scriptural support, I am always curious to verify the efficacy and veracity of this yoga without ignoring it all together.
2) Mangal Dosha(aka Sevvāi Dasha): Mangal Dosha is caused by Mars when he occupies in 2nd, 4th, 7th, 8th and 12th houses from either Lagna or Moon sign. Mostly this yoga is referred reckoning from Lagna ignoring the Moon sign(Chandra Lagna). Please refer my post at Quora platform for Details of this Mangal yoga.
3) Shani Dosha: There is no such Shani Dosha exists with scriptural support, but generally transit of Saturn effects Sade Sath Shani, Ashtama Shani, and Kantaka Shani reckoned from the Moon sign at birth, is harmful (but modifiable based current dasha and Bukti and other astrological factors). As far as horoscope is concerned, placement of Saturn in Trikona(1st, 5th and 9th), 2nd and 12th houses from Lagna(Ascendant) is bad. However based on Saturn's strength, association and aspects of benefic planets will modify the results. Please refer my post at Quora platform for Details of effect of Saturn in Transit as well as in Horoscope.
I) Your first question I have a question please. So I have so much bad luck mostly obstacles, betrayals, disappointments and lots of struggle.
Please check your current Dasha and Bukti. If your running Ashtamādhipati(8th lord), Satru Sthānadhipati(6th lord) or Viraya Sthanidipati(12th lord) as major dasha, marred with affliction at hands of Mars, Saturn, Sun, Rahu or Ketu, then it will be harmful. Your horoscope should be studied thoroughly in order to assess the damage. If your Lagnadhipati (Ascendant Lord) is afflicted being placed in Ashtama sthana(8th hosue), Satru sthana(6th house) or Viraya sthana(12th house) marred with affliction, then inherently you will face obstacles, opposition, disappoints, lack of rcognition and so on.

Position and strength of Lagnādhipati(Ascendant lord) is the key to the entire horoscope. Similarly strength of Chandra Lagnādhipati and Sūrya Lagnādhipati should also be scrutinized thoroughly. If all three Lagnādhipatis are weak, then the native will be in huge trouble.

Do you have Sun or Moon associated with Lagna? If so, the problem is severe. The Meaning is when Janma Lagna, Sūrya Lagna and Chandra Lagna fall in the same sign and if your running bad major dasha, then the cumulative effects will be very cruel. Are your Janma Lagna, the Moon sign or the Sun sign afflicted with malefic planets? Your birth chart requires a critical study. Please approach a competent astrologer.
II) Your second question I have Kalsarp Yog, Mangal Dosh, Shani Dosh.

You say the presence of Kāla Sarpha Yoga in your chart, but is it
complete? Does lagna escape from the clutches of this yoga? You must
verify that. What is the current running dasha? Is it Rahu or Ketu?
Mangal Dosha will throw its effects related to your marriage
prospects but not otherwise. If it is bad, at the most it may cause
injuries. Position and strength of Mars should be scrutinized for other
malefic results.
There is no such Shani dosha exists but check for Sade Sath Shani,
Ashtama Shani, and Kantaka Shani reckoned from your Moon sign. Is
Saturn badly placed in your chart? Make a sudharsan(सुदर्शन) analysis (i.e.
from Janma Lagna, chandra lagna and sūrya lagna separately)

III) Your third question I have done several pujas, Gemstone / Metal remedies, havans, prayers, but it seems like nothing is working. What could be reason that such a strong negative impacts in my life are not going away? What can a person do just adjust with it?

That is your Prārabdha Karma (प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) which
is a portion of the past heap of accumulated karma(aka Sanchita
Karma/सञ्चित कर्म/Accumulated) which is responsible for the present
embodiment, i.e. that subset of the Sanchita karma which influences
human life in the present incarnation is called Prārabdha. It is
ripe for reaping. It cannot be avoided or changed. It is only
exhausted by being experienced. You pay your past debts. Prārabdha
karma is that which has begun and is actually bearing fruit. It is a
subset and selected out of the mass of the Sanchita karma.

You have not listed the names of havans/pujas carried out so far.
Are they relevant to your chart?

you mentioned that all of your gem stone/Metal
parihāra(परिहार/prāyaścitta) were futile. were they properly
effected? You may be wearing irrelevant gems or without carrying out
proper rituals. Are your recharging(infusing energy) the stone every
month through Mantra Japa relevant to that gem(s)? If your wear gems
stones with inborn defects then instead of relief it may introduce
additional unwanted headaches! Please read my answer to the post in
this platform regarding wearing Gems and you particularly focus on
the comments section.


IV) Your fourth and final question Is there any permanent remedy to solve kalsarp yog and other doshas in one's kundali?

Please look for other Dur Yogas(दुर्योग) present in your chart such as
Sakata yoga(सकट योग), Papakarthri Yoga(पाप कर्तरी योग), Daridra Yoga(दरिद्र योग) and Kemadruma Yoga(केमद्रुम योग).

Is Moon without strength by being closer to the Sun?

Are any planets in Astangata(combustion) by being in close proximity
to the Sun? If so, then those planets are rendered powerless and will cause trouble during their dasha and bukti.

Check for the presence of Vipareeta Raja Yoga. What is Vipareeta Raja Yoga? If lords of evil houses (3rd, 6th, 8th and 12th) are strong, they increase the evil of horoscope i.e. poverty, debts, etc. If, on the  other hand, if they are weak and afflicted without any good influence, they destroy the evil in the horoscope and confer great wealth and affluence. This last cast constitutes what is known as Vipareeta Raja Yoga. i.e. yoga arising out of the weak position of bad planets! For example, in the case of Pisces Lagna, Sun is bad as lord of 6th house and if he occupies astamasthana(8th house) where he is in debilitation, then he becomes weak. Further if he is afflicted badly with aspects and/or association of malefic planets such as Mars, Saturn, Rahu or Ketu, then the Sun will qualify to effect this yoga during its dasha.

It seems that your Lagnadhipati (ascendant lord) may be without
strength and placed with affliction. Also your janma lagna may be
associated with malefic planets or receive aspects from them. If so, then wear proper defectless gem stones with proper rituals and observe monthly recharge procedure without fail.

Visit Kālahasti temple in Andra state to perform parihāra for
Rahu-Ketu. Contact Devasthāna office and purchase ticket to perform Pachchai karpūram Abhisekam (Green Camphor/aka Edible camphor/பச்சை கற்பூரம்/हरा कपूर) which should be preformed any day at Rāhu Kālam (राहुकाल). Also purchase a pair of Serpent idols, made in Silver, to be dropped in the hundial after puja. Be warned of huge assemblage of devotees for this Abhisekam, so be early at least by an hour and be seated at the front row for uninterrupted darshana. Beware-4: To know Rahu Kālam for the day, please refer panchāngam. For instance, if Sunday then it is from 4:30 PM to 6:00 PM. Beware-5: Like any other devotee, you will be also presenting your puja plate (vessel) filled with coconuts, bananas, thāmboolam (betel leaves and nuts), Agarbatti(Incense), red color vasthram, etc. In order to avoid the rush of collecting back the puja vessel from poojari (panda) after puja without missing, you just place some green ribbon  or some object/symbol in order to identify your plate. Beware-6: Upon the entry into the temple, don’t miss to visit the Phātāla Vināyagar (पाताल विनायक/Bhagavān Ganapathi under 30 feet down from the ground level) and take His blessings in order to remove obstacles before proceeding further. Beware-7: You need to plan and well prepared for this pilgrimage. Please read my Quora post that may be helpful while planning.

Unless other doshas are studied properly, remedy can't be
recommended.


Please consult a competent astrologer.
Good Luck!
